# GAS - data error for ScriptProperties.setProperty("myName", null);

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to learn about the ScriptProperties object in GAS.

I tried setting a property to a value of null, and I get an error.

I can understand if like JavaScript, setting a value of null undefines
that property.

But why are you disallowing this value? 
It seems reasonable (to me) to allow a script to undefine a script (or user) property.

Another question about ScriptProperties (and I assume the same holds for UserProperties),
Why when I display the value of an undefined property it displays as "undefined",
but when I try to test for the value "undefined" (without quotes) it does not match?

It seems, that if you are going to introduce a new special attribute value of "undefined", it should be consistent through out the system. If by "undefined" you mean null, well then
why not display it with the word "null"?

I am just trying to learn about this new environment. 
All help is appreciated. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [open feature request](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=236) to add support for removing properties, which you can star for updates.

The value "undefined" is not a string but rather a special value built in to JavaScript.  You can refer to it like "null":

```
if (foo == undefined) { ...
```

More information is available on the [w3schools page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_undefined.asp).